# Moq Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters cannot callback with parameters C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am pretty new to using Moq in C#, and I am trying to amend an existing test to take in some amended parameters, but when I try running the unit test, I am getting the error message

> " Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters cannot callback with parameters"

My mocked out method is thus:

```
 mockFileDeletionService
    .Setup(mq => mq.DeleteFileAndReport(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Uri>>(),It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Uri>>(),It.IsAny<IList<long>>(), false))
    .Callback<IEnumerable<Uri>,IEnumerable<Uri>,List<long>, bool>((files, directory, ids, types) => {
          filesIn = files;
          directIn = directory;
          idIn = ids;
          typesIn = types;
      })
    .Returns(results)
```

Sorry, but where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're specifying the third parameter type as `IList<long>` but specifying it in the callback templates as `List<long>`. I would try changing the `List` to `IList` and see what happens. That might not be your problem, though. Just something I noticed.

Comment: @kanders84152 that is the problem. They need to match up for the call back to work.

Comment: I have tried this and no difference

Comment: @Andy5 show the method that is being mock. and how it is being called in the method under test